# wget -O command not found

Tags: wget

This is my first day using Ubuntu 12.04. I am using Ubuntu as it is the only operating system capable of hosting an app I created using the statistical software package R. I am trying to follow the (so far very helpful) commands given at the following site:

http://withr.me/blog/2013/07/23/configure-shiny-server-under-ubuntu/

Everything runs fine until Step 6 - "Install Upstart script".

```
sudo wget\
https://raw.github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/master/config/upstart/shiny-server.conf\
-O /etc/init/shiny-server.conf
```

`command not found`

Any help as to why this error message is arising would be greatly appreciated. And sorry for the newbie question. Seriously only using Linux for a few hours.

Comment: You may need to install it first - run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install wget`. You can then test whether it works using `wget --version` or something. I would also think that running it as `sudo wget https://raw.github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/master/config/upstart/shiny-server.conf -O /etc/init/shiny-server.conf` would work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this one :-)

```
sudo wget -O /etc/init/shiny-server.conf  https://raw.github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/master/config/upstart/shiny-server.conf
```

You might have had a stray space after the \ or forgot to leave some room before it.
anyway, this line will work.

Comment: BTW you're doing great :-)  just a few hours on Ubuntu and already deep in the commandline. You actually deserve bonuspoints :-)

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much for the helpful tips!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets explain why you get `command not found`. What you are telling `sudo` to do is to execute the `wget\` command which do not exist. If you separate the `wget` from `\` you will see that it will work nicely:

```
sudo wget \
https://raw.github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/master/config/upstart/shiny-server.conf \
-O /etc/init/shiny-server.conf
```

The same happens with the second line. If you want you can make that into oneliner removing the returns and the backslash (`\`):

```
sudo wget https://raw.github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/master/config/upstart/shiny-server.conf -O /etc/init/shiny-server.conf
```

That's why it's not working

Comment: It's actually interpreting the command as: `bash: wgethttps://raw.github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/master/config/upstart/shiny-server.conf: No such file or directory`. `wget` and the first argument are concatenated together into the command name, which is not found.